# How to get a change of prop of useSlot() in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, slot, vue-render-function

I have a question about how to get the change of props retrieved from `useSlots()`

this is a file declaring Parent component with Child component as Parent component's slot. Also I passed some props to Child component.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Parent from "./components/Parent.vue";
import Child from "./components/Child.vue";

const name = ref("Nagisa");
function updateName() {
  name.value = "Daniel";
}
</script>

<template>
  <Parent><Child :name="name"></Child></Parent>
  <hr />
  <button @click="updateName">update name</button>
  <p>name: {{ name }}</p>
</template>
```

In Parent component, because of some limitations, I need to call `render function` and re-store what has been declared in `slot`.

```
// Parent component

<script setup>
import Child from "./Child.vue";
import { h, useSlots } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();
const defaultSlot = slots.default(); // <====== retrieving slot of Parent component

const render = (e) => {
  return h("div", {}, h(Child, defaultSlot[0].props)); <======= restoring Child with props coming from defaultSlot of Parent
};

// ========================
const render = (e) => {
  return h("div", {}, defaultSlot); <==== or alternatively this renders Child correctly
};
// ========================
</script>
<template>
  <render></render>
</template>
```

```
// Child component


<script setup>
defineProps(["name"]);
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    {{ name }}
  </div>
</template>
```

This correctly renders Child component with Parent component but Child component never updates if its prop value changes

[image]

After I click updateName button

[image]

Is there any way to catch and update the change of Child component's prop in Parent component from useSlot()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of slot in Parent is incorrect. Whole point of slots is to render *something* the Parent knows nothing about (ie. anything you pass to it). So rendering `Child` directly is wrong (as it tights Parent into always rendering Child instead of slot content)

Second problem is using `const defaultSlot = slots.default();` inside the `setup` - slots are functions and arguments of those functions (such as props and other reactive data from the parent scope) change when the template is re-rendered. So the *slot function* needs to be executed every time the Parent re-renders. But `setup` runs only once. This is why you don't see any update of Child. Instead use a slot directly in render function:

```js
// Parent component
<script setup>
import { h, useSlots } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();

const render = () => {
  return h("div", {}, slots.default ? slots.default() : null);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. but I have to do it this way because of the limitation of dependencies that Im using. And thank you so much for slots.default(), I did not realize that. this is what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer provided by @Michal Levy, you can also wrap your call to `default()` or any other `named slot`, in a `computed ref`.  This will allow the lookup to be lazy, cached, callable from the standard watch function, used outside the render function, and put directly in SFC templates.

```
<script setup>
import { h, useSlots } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();

const slotProps = computed(()=>slots.default ? slots.default().props : undefined)

watch(props, value), {
  console.log('props', value)
}, {immediate: true})

</script>
```

```
<template>
  <h1>Dynamic Slot Props</h1> 
  <div>{{slotProps}}
</template>
```